# SpringBoot Liquibase Oracle Junit test case execution fails

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, liquibase

I have a SpringBoot application in which i use Liquibase to generate oracle schema and tables.
When i run the application, it runs fine.

But when i try to run the Junit test case, it fails with below error,

```
Error creating bean name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource....
Migration failed for change set /db/changelog/....
Reason : liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Schema "XYZ" not found; SQL statement
```

The schema and tables are all present in the Database.

Still, why do i get this error?

Any suggestions please.

Comment: As you tagged your question with spring-boot, I guess you might be using `@ DataJpaTest` (or equivalent for other data access layer), is that correct?

Comment: Is this Spring Boot test? If yes. what is the configuration? What's the test context?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on Medium regarding the Schema Not Found part of your error.  Link: [Fix - Schema Not Found and Why](https://medium.com/@skywalkerhunter/fix-org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-schema-not-found-and-why-50debde657fa)

In step 3, the article recommends spring users add a file in your resource folder and name it schema-h2.sql. Within the file they give this example:

```
-- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testdb;
```

For step 4, you turn on your initialization-mode in your *.properties files. This will cause the schema-platform.sql files to be executed as expected.

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
```

When you reach step 5, make sure your platform name matches the *.sql file. the example they show in the screenshot in the article is shown below.

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
#spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=8
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.name=testdb
```

Then, double check all your schema names match perfectly, and you should be good to go.